# issue with counting digits of a number

Tags: javascript

Here is a code to count the digits of a given number.

There are two issues with this code that I can't fix without a hand:

**First**: If we have the function like `count(502.1000);` the output for decimals would be 1 instead of 4 ...

**Second**: If we have a number without decimals like `count(5024);` the output for numbers would be 1 instead of 4 ...

Here is the code:

```js
count(502.134); // Desired result is Numbers: 3 Decimals 3
count(502.1000); // Desired result is Numbers: 3 Decimals 4
count(5024); // Desired result is Numbers: 4 Decimals 0

function count(num) {
  
  Number.prototype.countDecimals = function () {
    if(Math.floor(this.valueOf()) === this.valueOf()) return 0;
    return this.toString().split(".")[1].length || 0; 
  }

  Number.prototype.countNumber = function () {
      if(Math.floor(this.valueOf()) === this.valueOf()) return 1;
      return this.toString().split(".")[0].length || 0; 
  }

  var a = Math.abs(num).countNumber(); 
  var b = Math.abs(num).countDecimals(); 

  console.log('Numbers: ' + a + ' Decimals '+ + b)
}
```

Comment: If you want trailing zeros to be included/counted, then you'll have to use strings instead of decimals.

Comment: Also, this doesn't make sense for counting digits: `if(Math.floor(this.valueOf()) === this.valueOf()) return 1;` -- It should return the *length*, not just `1`.

Comment: `return (this.toString().split(".")[0] || "").length;` fixes the countNumbers

Comment: Someone should make a dupe target for why inputting a number with trailing zeroes, and trying to get those zeroes in some way transformed as output, doesn't make any sense. This is being asked so often...

Comment: You have a typo in your `console.log` with an extra concat operator. Also, it's worth noting that you shouldn't be adjusting the number prototype this way. Every time the function is called it rewrites the methods onto the prototype which is a waste of processing. It's also a bit overkill, especially since you don't even perform both methods on the same number object. I would suggest just using locally scoped functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I thought it would be quicker to write my own function than analyse your code:

```js
function getDigitLength(num) {
  if (!num) {
      return;
  }

  const numString = num.toString();
  const split = numString.split('.');

  const numbers = split[0].length;

  const decimals = split[1] ? split[1].length : 0;

  console.log('Numbers: ' + numbers + ' Decimals '+ decimals);
}
```

Made this really quick, some refactoring could be done. It should result in what you are after though.

By the way, for this `count(502.1000); // Desired result is Numbers: 3 Decimals 4` is difficult because javascript will convert `502.1000` to `502.1`. Only if you pass `502.1000` as a string will it work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this . But only way(as pr my knowledge) 502.1000 will give proper result if you can convert that to string, not sure if that is possible in your implementation.

```
 var count = function(value) {
        var deccnt = 0;
        var numcnt = 0;
        try {
        deccnt = value.toString().split(".")[1].length || 0;
        } catch(e){}
        try {
        numcnt = value.toString().split(".")[0].length || 0;
        } catch(e){}
        alert(numcnt + " : " + deccnt);
    }

var num1 = 502.134;
    count(num1.toString())
    num1 = "502.1000";
    count(num1);
    num1 = 5024;
    count(num1.toString())
```